# Where is the text parameter in Tkinter Button class?

Tags: python, button, tkinter

Python beginner here!

I was learning Tkinter and when I came across creating a button, they used this:

```
quitButton = Button(self, text="Quit")
```

And I went to check the declaration of Button under tkinter module in the __init__ script and it shows:

```
class Button(Widget):
"""Button widget."""
......
......
```

**So my question is, Why are we able to pass a text parameter?**

Answer (score 3):

The `Button` class forwards all its keyword agruments (`**kw`) to its base class (`Widget`). You can see how it does that here

```
class Button(Widget):
    """Button widget."""
    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):
        """Construct a button widget with the parent MASTER.

        STANDARD OPTIONS

            activebackground, activeforeground, anchor,
            background, bitmap, borderwidth, cursor,
            disabledforeground, font, foreground
            highlightbackground, highlightcolor,
            highlightthickness, image, justify,
            padx, pady, relief, repeatdelay,
            repeatinterval, takefocus, text,
            textvariable, underline, wraplength

        WIDGET-SPECIFIC OPTIONS

            command, compound, default, height,
            overrelief, state, width
        """
        Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
```

Comment: I might have to study what \__init__ does to understand this.

Comment: `__init__ ` is called when an object is initialized (created). The python docs have a good write up on it [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects). Also you'll likely want to read up on inheritance also [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance)